# Assembly Help cmp doesn't work properly

Tags: assembly, x86

Problem is I am trying to code simple number comparison script but cmp doesn't work properly here is my code - thanks!

---

```
global _start
section .bss
number1:resb 3
number2:resb 3

section .data
da db "hello"
ll equ $-da
label1 db "enter the first number >>>"
len equ $-label1
label2 db "enter the second number >>>"
len2 equ $-label2
mess1 db "number 1 less than number 2",0ah
l1 equ $-mess1
mess2 db "number2 less than number 1",0ah
l2 equ $-mess2

section .text
_start:
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,label1
mov edx,len
int 80h
mov eax,3
mov ebx,2
mov ecx,number1
mov edx,3
int 80h
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,label2
mov edx,len2
int 80h
mov eax,3
mov ebx,2
mov ecx,number2
mov edx,3
int 80h

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,number1
mov edx,3
int 80h

mov ax,number1
mov bx,number2
cmp ax,bx
jl _ss1

_ss1:
   int 80h
   mov eax,4
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,da

   mov edx,ll
   int 80h

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0 
int 80h
```

Comment: Can you be more specific: what should this code do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/, and no comments so I don't even know what it's supposed to do.  This is very far from a [mcve].

Comment: In NASM, `mov ecx,number2` or `mov ax,number1` puts the *address* of the label into `ecx` or `ax`, not the value.  (You're using `resb`, so this is clearly NASM, and the Linux 32-bit `int 80h` system calls are another clue.)  I haven't memorized `asm/unistd_32.h`, and this code has no comments to say which system call is being invoked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `cmp` does work as it should, so your code just isn't written to fulfil your expectations, it's not *"`cmp` doesn't work properly"*. The CPU is fine, check in debugger that it does evaluate everything correctly, exactly as described in Intel instruction manual, it's not fault of CPU that you provided different values than you intended. Also while checking in debugger how the CPU works well, identify where the wrong values are coming from, and which part of your code is not working as expected, then fix your code to properly describe your original intention.

Comment: Your problem may be the `jl _ss1`.  If the comparison is "less," it's going to jump to _ss1.  What if it's not less?  Then it will just "fall thru" to the next statement.  Which is also _ss1.

Comment: I somehow suspect that after 35 years we would have realized if `cmp` doesn't work properly. :). You should learn how to use a debugger to step through your code.  If you do so, I suspect you will immediately see where you have gone wrongly.

Answer (score -1):

You need a jmp to the bottom of your code, that will skip over the label _ss1.  This will go just after the jl _ss1.

Comment: That's one problem ([which David Wohlferd's comment explained more clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320719/assemebly-help-cmp-doesnt-work-properly/50321162#comment87658118_50320719)).  A better fix would be to use `jnl` to jump somewhere else.  But that's hardly the only problem, e.g. `mov ax,number1` isn't a load, it's a mov-immediate of the address.  Still, this answer doesn't really deserve a downvote, because that *is* one of the bugs.